# How to filter String Array in VB.Net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, lambda, filter

What is VB.Net code to filter a String Array ?

I use following code

```
Imports System.Reflection
Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim resourceName() As String = ass.GetManifestResourceNames()
```

that return a String array

How can I filter resourceName() variable ?

I tried following lines of code

```
    Dim sNameList() As String 
        = resourceName.FindAll(Function(x As String) x.EndsWith("JavaScript.js"))
```

but compiler return following error

```
BC36625: Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'T()' because 'T()' is not a delegate type
```

How can I correct this error ?
Is there another solution to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim sNameList = resourceName.Where(Function(s) s.EndsWith("JavaScript.js"))
```

In that case, `sNameList` is an `IEnumerable(Of String)`, which is all you need if you intend to use a `For Each` loop over it. If you genuinely need an array:

```
Dim sNameList = resourceName.Where(Function(s) s.EndsWith("JavaScript.js")).ToArray()
```

The reason that your existing code didn't work is that `Array.FindAll` is `Shared` and so you call it on the `Array` class, not an array instance:

```
Dim sNameList = Array.FindAll(resourceName, Function(s) s.EndsWith("JavaScript.js"))
```

Comment: I'm confusing by Intellinsense that proposed FindAll() method when I enter a point just after resourceName ! But thanks for your help.